# How can you temporarily roll back a single file to a known good state in svn?

Tags: svn, rollback, single-file

I'm currently trying to return a single file to the state of a previous revision in subversion.  I don't want to commit the file, just leave it as a modification to the working copy for a bit.  How would I do that?

**Edit:**
It was suggested that I use checkout, but if I run the command that I would expect to work I get:

```
$ svn help checkout
checkout (co): Check out a working copy from a repository.
usage: checkout URL[@REV]... [PATH]


Valid options:
  -r [--revision] arg      : ARG (some commands also take ARG1:ARG2 range)
                             A revision argument can be one of:
                                NUMBER       revision number

$ svn checkout -r 133 templates/supplier.post_product.tpl
svn: Client error in parsing arguments
```

I guess perhaps I have to use a url to a directory instead of a path?

Comment: are yo using svn from the commandline, or are you using some sort of gui like turtoiseSVN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
svn up -r foo path/bar
```

Comment: I actually ended up having to scp the file up there and overwrite it, for now, but thanks, I'll keep that in mind for the next time I have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can individually `checkout` the older revision of the file, no commit necessary.